# Online editor for Kinetic Typography presentations?

Tags: video

Are there any web apps offer the ability to author Kinetic Typography presentations (panning, rotating, zooming text animations).

[image: zoomy text thing]

Here's an example of what I want to achieve using the web *(contains a few swear words)*:

**NSFW**: youtube.com/watch?v=Asvtgj6wANw

I had a look at [Prezi](http://prezi.com/) however it doens't support displaying text with time, everything has to be rendered before.

I am aware you can use post-effects video editors like After Effects however I was wondering if there is a simple web application that can achieve this?

Comment: It seriously doesn't look like there is anything web based. I ended up using Flash to make one (since I didn't have AE) http://www.vimeo.com/22832508. Question is still open if anyone does find something :)

Comment: Nice video, jay!  You may be the wrong person to ask, but do you think coding this in flash was easier, more difficult, more time-consuming that using After Effects might be?   

I'm guessing growing the "amazing just the way you are" tree took some time...

Comment: @charles: having seen the AE tutorials, I'd say go with AE. Flash is horrible for this kind of stuff. Not all my effects were transferred over, converting to video format was a nightmare, and the entire ordeal heavily time consuming. In summary DO NOT use Flash. My next vid is going to be AE (when I have the time)

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, No.

Time based text transformation is a processor hungry task. (Just ask anyone how much time does AE take to 'render' their videos and you'll know what I mean.)

Though I'm making an HTML5 based Javascript based Kinetic Typography. If I find it easy enough, it can be made into an app to allow basic transformations.

**June 2018 Update:**
Browsers have improved. CSS3 and HTML5 are now prevalent in Firefox and Chrome, and available even in Safari and Edge (laggards).

[This experiment](https://lab.tylergaw.com/themanfromhollywood/) shows a neat use with CSS animations (with minimal JS). And you can even [fork the code on Github and make your own](https://github.com/tylergaw/themanfromhollywood)! *(If you find a more elaborate Web-based Kinetic Type experience than this, do comment and let me know!)*

For something simpler, take a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/full/MwdoGb/).

And I highly recommend reading up and learning the animations. This germane tutorial shows how to get started: [Make a kinetic typography video with CSS](https://www.creativebloq.com/css3/make-kinetic-typography-video-css-5135642).

Comment: Seven years later... Did you find it easy enough? Any chances for a publication?

Comment: updated :)
Thanks @trejder

Comment: Thanks for response and update, however, it seems you have focused on providing CSS/HTML based solutions while OP's question was for a tool that allows you to produce actual presentations (downloadable) or videos (also downloadable). But, since the question is now off-topic, I don't think we want to work over it anymore! :>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Check this link: http://ddeubel.edublogs.org/2013/06/17/kinetic-typography-generator/

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the tool, you're talking about, needs Flash. It wasn't a problem back in 2013, it is a problem now, five years later, when Flash is no longer wanted by most.